How to get the bounds of a particular word or character using pdf.js library?
I am creating a Dart library by interoping the function call to the pdf.js library to search for a particular word in the PDF document, and I want to highlight matches.
In the dart application, only the pdf.min.js script will be included and not the pdf_viewer.min.js script.
Using the PdfJsPage.getTextContent function, we can get the offset, width, and height values of each line on the page. How can we get the bounds value of each word or each character in the line?
